# React test passes but component does not work properly when state updated in document.addListener handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a DatePicker component like this:

```
const MonthPanel = ({ setMode = () => {} }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => setMode("year")}
        data-testid="datepicker-year-button"
      >
        2021
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const YearPanel = () => {
  return <div data-testid="datepicker-year-panel">YearPanel</div>;
};

const DatePicker = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("month");
  const containerRef = useRef();

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleModeChange = (newMode) => {
    setMode(newMode);
  };

  const generatePanel = () => {
    switch (mode) {
      case "month":
        return <MonthPanel setMode={handleModeChange} />;
      case "year":
        return <YearPanel />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      if (containerRef.current && !containerRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        handleClose();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      data-testid="datepicker-container"
    >
      <div onClick={handleOpen} data-testid="datepicker-input">
        Select a date
      </div>
      {open && <div data-testid="datepicker-dialog">{generatePanel()}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I have a test file like this:

```
it.only("should close DatePicker dialog when clicked only outside DatePicker", () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(
      <DatePicker />
    );
    userEvent.click(getByTestId("datepicker-input"));
    userEvent.click(getByTestId("datepicker-year-button"));
    expect(queryByTestId("datepicker-dialog")).toBeInTheDocument();
    userEvent.click(document.body);
    expect(queryByTestId("datepicker-dialog")).toBeNull();
  });
```

#### Desired state:

When you click outside DatePicker, it should close. And when you click `[data-testid="datepicker-year-button"]` it should change DatePicker mode to "year", so the year panel will be shown.

#### Current state:

When you click `[data-testid="datepicker-year-button"]`, it changes Datepicker mode to "year" and MonthPanel (and with it button itself) are removed. Because the button is event target and has already removed, `containerRef.current.contains(e.target)` condition is `false` and Dialog will be removed too. But the test is showing that dialog is in the document.

The question is how I should test this functionality correctly.

Comment: are you sure that your test runner knows how to handle `document.body`?

Comment: it seems your desired state is actually that test fails when it should. You could update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `e.stopPropagation()` on your button click handler in `<MonthPanel>`, to prevent the event bubbling up and being caught by the `window`'s `eventListener`.

```
<button
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setMode("year");
    }}
    data-testid="datepicker-year-button"
>
```

Comment: I know that. The problem is the test have to fail, but it passes. I want to know what is wrong with my test and how I should test it.

Comment: So you're trying to make the test fail on purpose? You should probably mention that in the original post.

Comment: No. The code is not working correctly, right. So the test have to fail, but it passes. I ask what is wrong with my test.

Comment: What I mean was, you've changed the code to not work properly on purpose so that the test should fail. But in this instance it's not actually failing.

Comment: Yeah. That is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [async methods](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/) like `waitFor` or `waitForElementToBeRemoved`:

```
  await waitFor(() => {
     expect(queryByTestId("datepicker-dialog")).toBeNull();
  });
```

`React-dom` introduced `act API` to wrap code that renders or updates components, this makes your test run closer to how React works in the browser. React testing library wraps some of its APIs in the act function, but in some cases, you would still need to use waitFor, or waitForElementToBeRemoved

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `userEvent.click(document.body);` is not working properly.

Most likely `document.body` isn't resolved the way it should.
you're probably using testing-library user-event, and their basic example is:

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

test('types inside textarea', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<textarea />`

  userEvent.type(screen.getByRole('textbox'), 'Hello, World!')
  expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toHaveValue('Hello, World!')
})
```

check that your `document.body.innerHTML` is set to something